# Why don't modern web browsers display the "realm" value for HTTP authentication anymore?

Tags: http, authentication, browser, authorization

When hosting a website using HTTP Authentication, if the client has not authenticated, the server will send a 401 Unauthorized response, including a [WWW-Authenticate header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate). An optional directive in this header is `realm`:

> A string describing a protected area. A realm allows a server to partition up the areas it protects (if supported by a scheme that allows such partitioning), ***and informs users about which paricular username/password are required***.

(emphasis mine)

Let's say `www.example.com` requires authorization and has configured a realm value of `Test Area`. Back in the day, most web browsers would display a login dialog when receiving such a response, and say something along the lines of "Authorization required. The site at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) says 'Test Area'."

But (at least recent versions of) Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, now all just display a generic message, without including the realm value. Interestingly enough, IE still displays the realm value (screenshots below, all Windows 10 64bit):

### Chrome (v93.0.4577.82)

[image: chrome no realm]

### Firefox (v92.0)

[image: firefox no realm]

### Edge (v93.0.961.52)

[image: edge no realm]

### IE (v11.1411.18362.0)

[image: IE has realm]

I'm pretty sure Firefox and Edge used to display it. Chrome may have a while back but seems like it was the first to stop. Since all modern browsers aren't displaying it, I assume there's some reason why..?? I've search all over the internet, and can't figure it out. I have a use-case where it would be helpful to users to have the realm displayed, as it would make it clearer which particular credentials they need to use. I know that you can't force the browser to display it, but it's just annoying. However if there is a valid reason for it not being shown I'll accept that.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Realm database (per your tag), part of MongoDB Realm?

Comment: @Jay It doesn't -- I just used the tag 'realm' which could refer to anything named realm lol. I guess it's too general of a word to be a useful tag though

Comment: Understood. Tag's are very specific elements here in SO - if you hover over a tag it will indicate what it's for and how it applies (and other useful info). The tags are how SO categorizes questions to put the right sets of eyeballs on it to increase your chances of an answer by someone with experience in that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that this could be abused for phishing attacks, by putting some misleading message into the realm. The login dialog for http authentication is part of the trusted browser UI, and giving the server the opportunity to modify that UI - even by just displaying text - is a security risk.

Comment: I didn't even think of that, but it totally makes sense. Thanks!